# Angular POST caused The origin 'http://evil.com/' is not allowed

Tags: angularjs, cors

I'm trying to POST to WebApi backend this way:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('auth', []).factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', '$localStorage', function ($http, $q, $localStorage) {

    var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:53432/api/';
    var authServiceFactory = {};

    var authentication = {
        isAuth: false,
        userName: ""
    };

    var saveRegistration = function (registration) {
        return $http.post(serviceBase + 'account/register', registration).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });

    };
```

But I got error `"message":"The origin 'http://evil.com/' is not allowed."`
I'm understand that it's related to CORS issue, so I define in module `$sceDelegateProvider`:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'http://localhost:53432' //This is webapi url
        ]);
```

But this didn't helped as well. How should I fix this?

On server side CORS enabled already:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [Route("Register")]
 [HttpPost]
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel register)
```

Comment: You need to enable CORS of your serverside (webapi)

Comment: `"message":"The origin 'http://evil.com/' is not allowed."` what is this `url`? Even it is not there in your code

Comment: Are you sure that the error you mentioned is related the code you added?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect, no, I'm not. But CORS already enabled on server side.

Comment: Try using $http.jsonp in order to skip CROS issues

Comment: @Mr_Perfect, url for this call is http://localhost:53432/api/account/register

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's funny, but the problem was solved by turning off the CORS plugin in the browser.

---

Solution pulled from question, written by [andrey.shedko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924646/andrey-shedko).

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue

You are using an extension that is using evil.com to make requests, so the 'localhost:....' won't work, since the 'origin' is not actually 'localhost:...'.

Turn off the plugin and it will work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Sorry for not being clear about my thoughts

Answer (score 1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set on the response from server, not on client request to allow clients from different origins to have access to the response.

Your JavaScript can't grant itself permission to access another website.

If you are use webapi so please read this and how to do enable CORS for other website request.
https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I think this will be help full to you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complement @Thomas Pessato, in the case of **Angular** I was using a plugin called "**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin**" as a Chrome Extension. This was adding the "origin http:/ /evil.com".
Turning it off solved the problem.